# Do .rpm files installed with rpm get update notices from dnf check-update?

Tags: rpm, dnf, software-updates

This (longer set of instructions for ex: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) shows how to get the repo installed and then goes on to dnf.

This direct .rpm (https://code.visualstudio.com/download) info page doesn't say whether dnf will report updates or whether finding out about avail update notifications is a manual process or whether "I'm on my own" update-wise.

I haven't been able to find any clue or doc that says how dnf check-update handling might differ when the install is done, not via dnf -install, but with rpm -i.

I'm confused about, 'cuz I haven't understood enough or read enough, whether dnf check-update will inform me that packages installed with rpm -i are due for update.

The 1st version mentioned sets up the key and the repo.
The 2nd is just an .rpm. I have no idea whether the .rpm alone will get me dnf check-update results. It doesn't say, and vscode updates frequently.

Comment: Related, from Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/n320wb/if_i_install_a_package_from_a_rpm_file_will_it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dnf` will check the repos for packages to be updated. If you install alone `rpm` `dnf` have no information when there is new version.

And to avoid warnings/problems with `rpm` database use command:

```
dnf localinstall http:/host/path/name.rpm
```

instead of download it and install it via `rpm`